# Is the following set open or closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, y \ge 1\}$.

I can see that $A=\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, y < 1\}$, but then the question is is $U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, y < 1\}$ open? I think it is since it seems possible to find open balls around each point that are contained in the set.

Comment: Your last remark is correct and $U$ is open. Now let $(x,y) \in U$ and find an appropriate $\epsilon$ so that $B((x,y), \epsilon) \subseteq U$.

Comment: " I think it is since it seems possible to find open balls around each point that are contained in the set."  Right.  So .... do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because for any point $(x_0, y_0)$ in $U$, the open ball $B((x_0,y_0),r = \frac{1-y_0}{2})$ belongs to $U$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto y$.  Since $f$ is continuous and $V:=]-\infty, 1[$ is open in $\mathbb R$, $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ as preimage of $V$ under $f$.